# How to draw a line in canvas with a background image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a line in canvas (which I can do), but I want to put a repeating pattern on the line using a background image (unless there is another way to put a repeating background image on a line in canvas?).

How can I draw a line with a background image?

I understand the concept of clipping, but that only seems to work with shapes... not with a stroke. Any ideas?

Here is a jsfiddle of what I was trying
http://jsfiddle.net/Z9cd7/

```
    function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

var radius = 50;
var x = 100;
var dx = 10;
var y = 100;
var dy = 10;
var delay = 10;
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById("image");
    var ctxImg = canvas1.getContext("2d");
    ctxImg.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    /*
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 100, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore();
    */
    ctx.moveTo(0,0)
    ctx.lineTo(100,100)
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.stroke()

    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore();

    //animate();
}
img.src = "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_Z-i7eF_ACGI/TRxpFywLCxI/AAAAAAAAAD8/ACsxiuO_C1g/house%20vector.png";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two solutions :

- Build the polygon that corresponds to the thick line, then fill it with your image as pattern. Basically this requires to compute the tangent and do a little math. i wrote a small article about a similar issue here :
   http://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/variable-width-lines-in-html5-canvas/
  you can see the fiddle here :  http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/GCwVU/

The code is this one, basically you want a varLine with w1 = w2 (same start / end thickness) ;

```
// varLine : draws a line from A(x1,y1) to B(x2,y2)
// that starts with a w1 width and ends with a w2 width.
// relies on fillStyle for its color.
// ctx is a valid canvas's context2d.
function varLine(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, w1, w2) {
    var dx = (x2 - x1);
    var dy = (y2 - y1);
    w1 /= 2; // we only use w1/2 and w2/2 for computations.
    w2 /= 2;
    // length of the AB vector
    var length = Math.sqrt(sq(dx) + sq(dy));
    if (!length) return; // exit if zero length
    var shiftx = -dy * w1 / length; // compute AA1 vector's x
    var shifty = dx * w1 / length; // compute AA1 vector's y
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1 + shiftx, y1 + shifty);
    ctx.lineTo(x1 - shiftx, y1 - shifty); // draw A1A2
    shiftx = -dy * w2 / length; // compute BB1 vector's x
    shifty = dx * w2 / length; // compute BB1 vector's y
    ctx.lineTo(x2 - shiftx, y2 - shifty); // draw A2B1
    ctx.lineTo(x2 + shiftx, y2 + shifty); // draw B1B2
    ctx.closePath(); // draw B2A1
    ctx.fill();
}
```

- Second solution is very quick : use the globalCompositeOperation modes to do the clipping for you.
  for instance draw the line, use 'source-in', then draw the image on top of the line.
  This is very handy, but the issue here is that it will work only if the canvas was clean before the line draw. If you can choose freely drawing order, this is not an issue, otherwise, you'll have to draw the line in a temp canvas, then draw the canvas on the main canvas.

Updated fiddle is here : 
 http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/Z9cd7/1/

[image]

Edit : fiddle for the image with repetitions :
http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/Z9cd7/2/

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be working. Is there a way to make it so the image repeats on the x and y axis?

Comment: You're welcome. You are talking about the second solution, i guess : sure : instead of drawImage, fillRect with a pattern based on the image (that you create only once on image load (creating a pattern does a copy, so do not create pattern in loops/animations)).

Comment: @Bill : i just made a small example for the repeat.

Comment: Thanks... got it from your comment... just needed a point in the right direction!

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to be 100% sure the advice was good and share the image ! :-)

Answer (score 6):

I bit late but as there is no need to use neither clipping or calculating vectors you could perhaps consider using the built-in support for this (which is faster) by simply setting a stroke style with an image pattern as style:

```
var pattern = ctx.createPattern(image, 'repeat');  /// create pattern
ctx.strokeStyle = pattern;                         /// set as stroke style

ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.stroke();                           /// strokes with the image as background
```

## [Demo 1 here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9cd7/4/)

[image: Pattern as stroke]

If you want to change the pattern size just change the size of the canvas ("`image`") you're using in this case:

```
<canvas id="image" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

And with modification in your `onload` handler so image is scaled to fit the canvas:

```
ctxImg.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
```

## [Demo 2 here](http://jsfiddle.net/wCn7a/1/)

[image: Smaller pattern]

If you need to adjust the position of the pattern when drawing you can use `translate()` using a delta value which you first translate with and then subtract to the positions of the lines you want to draw with the pattern - that will keep the lines in the same position as before translating but move the pattern itself:

```
ctx.translate(dx, dy);
ctx.moveTo(x1 - dx, y1 - dy);
ctx.lineTo(x2 - dx, y2 - dy);
...
```

Comment: Yep, I keep forgetting the usefulness of patterns--my darned memory :)  In your demo#2 is the `delay` meant to eventually control the spacing between the repeated patterns?

Comment: @markE oh, the `delay` ++ are just leftovers from OPs original fiddle. I just cut a little around the essential to make it more clear (as in the answer) - I didn't clear the other bits (to leave the code somewhat recognizable to OP).

Comment: This worked great for me, but you missed one line:

`cxt.beginPath();`

above 

`ctx.moveTo(10, 10);`

in Demo 1.  Without that, if you call this multiple times it will redraw all previous draw operations, instead of just the latest line

Answer (score 1):

**[ Using an image to draw a line ]**

You can use this utility function to determine any percentage point along a line segment:

```
    function getLineXYatPercent(startPt,endPt,percent) {
        var dx = endPt.x-startPt.x;
        var dy = endPt.y-startPt.y;
        var X = startPt.x + dx*percent;
        var Y = startPt.y + dy*percent;
        return( {x:X,y:Y} );
    }
```

After that it's just a bit-of-math to repeatedly position your image along each line segement:

```
    var dx=points[i].x-points[i-1].x;
    var dy=points[i].y-points[i-1].y;
    var length=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    var pctImage=imgWidth/length;
    for(var pct=pctImage/2;pct<1.00;pct+=pctImage){
         var pos=getLineXYatPercent(points[i-1],points[i],pct);
         ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,pos.x,pos.y,imgWidth,imgHeight);
    }
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/R278u/

[image]

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: lightgray; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();
    var isDown=false;

    var points=[];
    points.push({x:0,y:0});
    points.push({x:100,y:125});
    points.push({x:200,y:75});
    points.push({x:300,y:100});

    imgWidth=20;
    imgHeight=20;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        draw();
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/house%20vector.png";

    function draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
        for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
            var p=points[i];
            var dx=points[i].x-points[i-1].x;
            var dy=points[i].y-points[i-1].y;
            var length=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
            var pctImage=imgWidth/length;
            for(var pct=pctImage/2;pct<1.00;pct+=pctImage){
                var pos=getLineXYatPercent(points[i-1],points[i],pct);
                ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,pos.x,pos.y,imgWidth,imgHeight);
            }   
        }
    }

    function getLineXYatPercent(startPt,endPt,percent) {
        var dx = endPt.x-startPt.x;
        var dy = endPt.y-startPt.y;
        var X = startPt.x + dx*percent;
        var Y = startPt.y + dy*percent;
        return( {x:X,y:Y} );
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Trailing line based on interpolation looks nice!

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you just drawing over everything with the second drawImage call?

edit : you are, but that's not what you mean, try beginning and closing the path

```
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(0,0)
 ctx.lineTo(100,100)
 ctx.lineTo(100,0);
 ctx.closePath()
 ctx.lineWidth = 10;
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.clip();

 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: no big issue here, but your post should rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: Why? I was offering a potential answer, that the second drawImage call was drawing over the whole canvas. So therefore I'm offering an answer not making a comment.

Comment: before your edit, this was a one-line post, that's all. Try providing code and a fiddle, my attempt to make your idea work failed...