# HTML5 Canvas / Clip region in a line

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, clip

I was wondering if there is any solution for setting the stroke of a line as part of a clipping region.

We can easily set a clipping region like this :

```
this.upperCtx.save();
    this.upperCtx.beginPath();
    this.upperCtx.arc(0, 0, 40, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    this.upperCtx.clip();
    this.upperCtx.drawImage(this.downCanvas, 0, 0);
this.upperCtx.restore();
```

But my problem is that I'm trying to create a clip region on a line with the following :

```
this.upperCtx.save();
    this.upperCtx.lineWidth = 80;
    this.upperCtx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
    this.upperCtx.beginPath();
    this.upperCtx.moveTo(0, 0);
    this.upperCtx.lineTo(30, 30);
    this.upperCtx.stroke();
    this.upperCtx.clip();
    this.upperCtx.drawImage(this.downCanvas, 0, 0);
this.upperCtx.restore();
```

And this doesn't work. I have made some searches and haven't found any solutions.

I think that clip only affect "fill" part of the path and not stroke one.

If anyone have a solution. Thanks !

Comment: your question is very similar to this one, and my answer should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483829/how-to-draw-a-line-in-canvas-with-a-background-image/21484368#21484368

Comment: Thanks @GameAlchemist, it's indeed quite the same problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw a line in canvas with a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483829/how-to-draw-a-line-in-canvas-with-a-background-image)